# How to load model with unshaded material?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I'm making a game on JMonkeyEngine 3, I'm working on design.
I made and added walls, ceiling, floor, and some models.

But after I run my game, it lags. I don't need any light effects, so I want to load anything with `Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md` MaterialDef to reduce lagging.

I'm loading my models like this: (they all are in glb format, I can't translate them
to j3o because I'm using IntelliJ IDEA)

`Spatial model = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Model.glb");`

I don't need to set material because glb file format includes it.

And as default, we have lighting MaterialDef. But I don't want it.

How can I set model's MaterialDef to unshaded? Or load it with unshaded material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example about materials in the [official JMonkey Engine Documentation](https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/docs/3.3/core/material/material_definitions.html) shows, how to load and apply the unshaded material. Just apply it to the geometry you loaded into your game.

Your question is similar to [this one](https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/texture-of-glb-does-not-load/45588), which was posted to the official JMonkey Engine forum.

Comment: @Yarik0urWorld: Was my answer helpful? If not, tell me why :)